# UIMA Ruta: Copy the feature value from a contained annotation to a containing annotation

Tags: uima, ruta

Note: This seems heavily related to [Setting feature value to the count of containing annotation in UIMA Ruta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812029/setting-feature-value-to-the-count-of-containing-annotation-in-uima-ruta). But I cannot quite apply the answer to my situation.

I am analyzing plain text documents where the following structure is assumed:

- Document (one, of course)

  - Section (many)

    - Heading (one per section)

I am being asked to identify sections by checking whether their headings satisfy conditions. A useful and obvious sort of condition would be: **does the heading match a given regular expression?** A less-useful but perhaps more achievable condition would be: **does the heading contain a given text**?

I could and have already achieved this by taking a list of tuples of regular expressions and section titles, and at design time, for each member of the list, as such:

```
BLOCK(forEach) SECTION{} {
    ...
    HEADING{REGEXP(".*table.*contents.*", true) -> 
            SETFEATURE("value", "Table of Contents")};
    ...
}

SECTION{ -> SETFEATURE("value", "Table of Contents")} 
         <- { HEADING.headingValue == "Table of Contents"; };
```

This approach is fairly straightforward but has a few big drawbacks:

1. It heavily violates the DRY principle
2. Even when writing the rule for just one section to identify, the rule author must copy the section title twice (it should only need to be specified once)
3. It makes the script needlessly long and unwieldy
4. It puts a big burden on the rule author, who in an ideal case, would only need to know Regex - not Ruta

So I wanted to refactor to achieve the following goals:

- A text file is used to store the regular expressions and corresponding titles, and the rule iterates over these pairs
- Features, rather than types, are used to differentiate different sections/headings (i.e. like above, using `SECTION.value=="Table of Contents"` and not `TableOfContentsSection`)

After looking over the UIMA Ruta reference to see which options were available to achieve these goals, I settled on the following:

1. Use a `WORDTABLE` to store tuples of `section title, words to find / regex if possible, lookup type` - so for instance, `Table of Contents,contents,sectiontitles`
2. Use `MARKTABLE` to mark an intermediate annotation type `LookupMatch` whose `hint` feature contains the section title and whose `lookup` feature contains the type of lookup we are talking about
3. For each `HEADING`, see if a `LookupMatch.lookup == "sectiontitle"` is inside, and if it is, copy the `LookupMatch.hint` to the heading's `value` field.
4. For each `SECTION`, see if a `HEADING` with a `value` is inside; if so, copy the `value` to the `SECTION.value` field.

It was not quite a surprise to find that implementing steps 3 and 4 was not so easy. That's where I am at and why I am asking for help.

```
// STEP 1

WORDTABLE Structure_Heading_WordTable =
    '/uima/resource/structure/Structure_Heading_WordTable.csv';

// STEP 2

Document.docType == "Contract"{
    -> MARKTABLE(LookupMatch,                                       // annotation
                 2,                                                 // lookup column #
                 Structure_Heading_WordTable,               // word table to lookup
                 true,                                              // case-insensitivity
                 0,                                                 // length before case-insensitivity
                 "",                                                // characters to ignore
                 0,                                                 // matches to ignore
                 "hint" = 1, "lookup" = 3                           // features
                 )
};

// STEPS 3 AND 4 ... ???

BLOCK(ForEach) LookupMatch.lookup == "sectiontitle"{} {
    ???
}

HEADING{ -> SETFEATURE("value", ???)} <- {
    ???
};
```

Here is my first real stab at it:

```
HEADING{ -> SETFEATURE("value", lookupMatchHint)} <- {
    LookupMatch.lookup == "HeadingWords"{ -> GETFEATURE("hint", lookupMatchHint)};
};
```

### TL; DR

How can I conditionally copy a feature value from one annotation to another? `GETFEATURE` kind of assumes that you only get 1...

Comment: Without testing: Did the rule work for you and answered your question?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "you only get 1"? One value as in String vs StringList or one String per rule apply?